# Is there modern evidence that the Sun stood still?

Tags: history, miracles, science, joshua

Has anyone presented tangible, astronomical evidence of a disruption we can see today that is claimed to be caused by the Sun/Moon "stopping" roughly 3500ish years ago as it says in Joshua 10? Has any prominent figure made any scientific observations that would point to some Sun/Moon stopping event?

> **Joshua 10:12-14 ESV** At that time Joshua spoke to the Lord in the day when the Lord gave the Amorites over to the sons of Israel, and he said in the sight of Israel, “Sun, stand still at Gibeon, and moon, in the Valley of Aijalon.” **And the sun stood still**, and the moon stopped, until the nation took vengeance on their enemies. Is this not written in the Book of Jashar? The sun stopped in the midst of heaven and did not hurry to set for about a whole day. There has been no day like it before or since, when the Lord heeded the voice of a man, for the Lord fought for Israel.

I am assuming a literal interpretation of this passage--that the Sun and Moon somehow "stopped", be it miraculous or God just timing it perfectly or otherwise.

Related: [Did the sun and the moon really stop rotating?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15498/11471). I'm looking for an example of a scientist saying "this is my evidence for it" rather than "these are all the ways it could happened."

Comment: If the events of the Bible were provable, Christianity would then be knowledge and not faith.

Comment: @Bye I understand what you're saying. God wants our faith. But there are lots of events in the Bible that are provable and I'm just asking about one.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but what is not provable is the existence of God and since that would be a proven act of God, would it not also be proof of his existence?

Comment: @Bye How do we know it was a miracle? How do we know God had to break the natural laws to do it. I think it's just as possible that God "timed" planetary motion perfectly so the galaxy remained "still" for 24 hours. And if he did that, there might be evidence for it. Hence my original question.

Comment: please reread your Scripture reference. Does it say Joshua or God did it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about scientific evidence for a historical even that just happens to be described in the Christian Scripture. Unless this is couched as asking for a doctrinal stance, or other official teaching, this is off-topic.  This site isn't for sciengtific evidence of any sort, it's solely focuses on established Christian doctrines and teachings.

Comment: [This meta post relates to this, especially the science part.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3480/3961)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are "looking for an example of a scientist saying "this is my evidence for it"", then the answer is no, there is no credible evidence of it. If there were, it would be common knowledge because it would be so out of the ordinary.

Also, it's interesting to note that for the Sun to stop moving across the sky, that would actually mean the Earth would have (almost) stopped spinning, because it's the Earth spinning that causes the Sun to *appear* to move.

For fun, if the Earth stopped spinning suddenly...

The ground under your feet, and your body itself, is currently moving at about 1000 miles per hour (less if you are closer to the poles) due to the Earth spinning. If the Earth suddenly stopped spinning, you would be thrown to the East at that speed, like when you hit the breaks hard in your car at 60 mph you are thrown at the windshield. The oceans lakes and streams would be thrown as well, waves of water would crash over everything.

Also, the Earth is not a perfect sphere, it's actually wider than it is tall, due to the force generated by the spinning motion (think of spinning on your feet -- your arms will be pulled outwards). This also includes the water on the Earth. So, if it were just the Earth ceasing to spin, then the oceans would (after stopping their 1000 mph scouring the landscape), due to the force of gravity, start settling to create a spherical shape -- which would flood the north and south of the Earth and expose the ocean floors around the equator!

The atmosphere is also spinning. Suddenly there would be 1000 mph winds from west to east. Not that you would feel them -- you'd be flying inside them.

Of course, when stopping the Earth from spinning, it would be a good idea to stop all the things on and in it from spinning, too!

Anyway, it's all illustrative of the fact those verses are written by/for people who don't know that it is the Earth that moves around the Sun and not the other way around.

I'm not sure the Earth or Sun stopping for a day that long ago in history could be proven scientifically other than by it being recorded by people. So a related question to ask would be, did anyone else record the Sun stopping at that time in history? This should have been a world wide event, unless it was some kind of local illusion. What other civilizations existed at the time, and did any of them record it?  However, it's hard to find similar evidence for things we *know* happened -- for example, Halley's Comet appears every 75-76 years, but until only about 1000 years ago, it is hard to find multiple accounts of it from the same year. It may have been recorded twice in 467 BC when a comet was recorded both in Greece and in China (check the Halley's Comet Wikipedia page).

Comment: But if God could miraculously stop and restart the Earth spinning then he would be capable of doing so in a non-dangerous way.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Yes, of course :). I joke and say that doing so is a good idea (insofar as doing so safely in order to enable maximal killing is a good idea?); the disaster stuff was just for fun.  I suppose the way to do it safely would be to stop the Earth and Moon, but distort spacetime around them so the deceleration would not be felt. The side-effects of that (on say small moons/debris in Earth's orbit), I have no idea.

Comment: Well if we're going for maximum disaster then the earth's angular momentum should be redistributed to every person and animal. I don't think that would be very healthy.

Comment: Here is the historical evidence from all over the world of "the day the sun stood still" - https://youtu.be/zP-cIjo46SE  Secondly if God can make "the sun stand still"  He could definitely inspire the author of the book of Joshua to write what actually happened that day correctly! If the author was inspired by God, and I believe he was, said, "the sun stood still" than that's what happened - the sun stood still! Then you have to ask yourself - if the sun is moving-than the earth isn't! Read Psa 19:6 - The Bible clearly and unequivocally says the earth is fixed and the sun is moving!  Blessings

Answer (score 6):

I had heard about NASA finding a missing day that proved that the earth stood still, however [it does not seem to be true](https://answersingenesis.org/creationism/arguments-to-avoid/nasa-found-joshuas-missing-day/). There does not seem to be any evidence other than the Word of God, and I cannot see how there really would be evidence of this.

Comment: Snopes pounced on it too http://www.snopes.com/religion/lostday.asp